# Getting error "NameError: name 'letter' is not defined"

Tags: python-2.7, nameerror

I'm fairly new to python and don't know much but i tried to make a program that sees how fast it can guess a string in this case a password. I tried to create an individual variable for each letter by making a loop that sets the variable. (I added the print letter1... at the end  so i can see if it works).Then when i went to test it i got this error.

> letter[x] = password[x - 1:-(len(password)-1)]
>
> NameError: name 'letter' is not defined

```
print "Password guesser"

password = raw_input('Enter Password (1-30 carechters only): ')
passwordLength= len(password)

for x in range(0,passwordLength):
    letter[x] = password[x - 1:-(len(password)-1)]

print letter1
print letter2
print letter3
```

Comment: What the heck are `letter`, `letter1`, `letter2`, and `letter3`? They are not defined in the code... read the error

Comment: `letter` is not declared before you try to assign to it. For that kind of assignment to work letter would have to be a list that is at least `x` + 1 items in length.

Comment: @PaulRooney when i tried doing  adding `letter = ''` to declare it before it would give me this error:

Comment: @PaulRooney It would give me TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: it wont work with a string. strings are immutable, you cannot change the values of characters. Thats why it would need to be a list. You may as well change it to `letter.append(password[x - 1:-(len(password)-1)])` where letter is defined as `letter = []` before your loop. If you can get a correct value in your list you can `join` it back up to be a string at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're assigning letters with dictionary syntax, you may want to declare the `letter` variable as a dictionary: `letter = {}`, then output it as a dictionary. This may get you in the direction you want to go:

```
letter = {}

for x in range(passwordLength):
    letter[x] = password[x - 1:-(passwordLength-1)]

print letter[0]
print letter[1]
print letter[2]
```

Comment: OK this worked but when i entered the string it only outputted the first letter and the rest just blank :/

Comment: that's just due to the assignment you give to letter, those other values don't get set. maybe you want `letter[x] = password[x]`? but this would only be copying the password string to letter string..

Comment: oh yes this works now i just had to add a -1 to the x but now its fine. thanks